# Setting UITableViewCell from array crashed simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have tried so many things to make this work and I have failed completely.

I get the following error

`-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d41210
2011-01-31 17:03:49.496 IHaulage[11954:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d41210`

My Code looks like the following

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"FIRST LINE ROW");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    // Set up the cell...

     hold = [self.names objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    //NSString *hold = [big objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"%@",hold);
    //hold = @"TEST TEST";
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    cell.textLabel.text = hold; 
    return cell;

}
```

If I uncomment the `hold = @"test test"` the table populates properly with "test test"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hi",nil];
    DataManager *sharedManager = [DataManager sharedManager];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" 
                     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap= \"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\" > "
                     "<soap:Header/>"
                     "<soap:Body>"
                     "<tem:LookupContractors>" 
                     "<tem:haulerId>%@</tem:haulerId>"
                     "</tem:LookupContractors>"
                     "</soap:Body>"
                     "</soap:Envelope>",sharedManager.userID];
    NSLog(sharedManager.userID);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ihaulage.com/wcf/haulageservice.svc"];   
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];     
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/IHaulageService/LookupContractors" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: theRequest delegate:self];

    if(conn) 
    {     
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    } else {     
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL"); 
    }

    if (xmlParser)
    {
        [xmlParser release];
    }    
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParser parse];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{    
    if (xmlParser)
    {
        [xmlParser release];
    }    
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParser parse];  
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (elementFound)
    {
        SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
        statuses = (NSArray *)[parser objectWithString:string error:nil];
        for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
        {
             [self.names addObject:[status objectForKey:@"Name"]];
            NSLog(@"%@",[status objectForKey:@"Name"]);
            NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@ - %@ - %@",[status objectForKey:@"ID"], [status objectForKey:@"Name"],[status objectForKey:@"Fax"],[status objectForKey:@"Email"],[status objectForKey:@"company"]);
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",[names objectAtIndex:1]);
        [parser release];
        [contractor_list reloadData];
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
}
```

### .h file

```
@interface ManageContractors : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *contractor_list;
    NSArray *statuses;
    NSString *hold;
    NSString *current;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

    //---web service access---
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSMutableString *soapResults;
    NSURLConnection *conn;
    NSMutableArray *names;

    //---xml parsing---
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
    BOOL *elementFound;
    BOOL *table;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *contractor_list;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *names;

@end
```

Sorry for the huge amount of code but I think if I showed more I could get more help possibly

I do not know what is causing this error. My Json parse is correct and my names array fills up correctly its when I want to dispaly it to the table where it falls apart completely

```
 2011-02-01 10:11:40.606 IHaulage[15827:207] -[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b29560
2011-02-01 10:11:40.607 IHaulage[15827:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b29560'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db9be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f0e5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dbb6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d2b366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d2af22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x003e1340 -[UILabel setText:] + 72
    6   IHaulage                            0x0000746e -[ManageContractors tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 434
    7   UIKit                               0x003367fa -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
    8   UIKit                               0x0032c77f -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x00341450 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
    10  UIKit                               0x00339538 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01c77451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01c7717c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01c7037c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01c700d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    15  QuartzCore                          0x01ca07d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d9afbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d300e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf8bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf8240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf8161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x016ee268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x016ee32d GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x002d142e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  IHaulage                            0x00001ad8 main + 102
    25  IHaulage                            0x00001a69 start + 53
    26  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

The foolowing is the stack trace log i did when debuggin with the breakpoint

```
#0  -[ManageContractors tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (self=0x4b56490, _cmd=0x6dfd5f, tableView=0x5048c00, indexPath=0x8d163f0) at /Users/mdedys/Dropbox/iHaulage Code/iPhone/IHaulage/Classes/ManageContractors.m:49
#1  0x003367fa in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] ()
#2  0x0032c77f in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] ()
#3  0x00341450 in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] ()
#4  0x00339538 in -[UITableView layoutSubviews] ()
#5  0x01c77451 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#6  0x01c7717c in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded ()
#7  0x01c7037c in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#8  0x01c700d0 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#9  0x01ca07d5 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#10 0x00d9afbb in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#11 0x00d300e7 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#12 0x00cf8bd7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x00cf8240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x00cf8161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x016ee268 in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x016ee32d in GSEventRun ()
#17 0x002d142e in UIApplicationMain ()
#18 0x00001ad8 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffeff0) at /Users/mdedys/Dropbox/ihaulage code/iPhone/IHaulage/main.m:14
```

Comment: The problem is wherever you have isEqualToString: you are calling this method on an array instead of a string. Post the code where that is.

Comment: I dont have that anywhere. I dont use isEqualToString anywhere..

Comment: Do you have the complete stack trace? That would help a lot. Also, have you confirmed that `NSLog(@"%@",[status objectForKey:@"Name"]);` is indeed printing `NSStrings`?

Comment: when it hits this line cell.textLabel.text = hold;  I posted the error logs in my original question I am pretty sure its a string, is there a way to test that it is for sure a string?

Comment: when I dont populate the table but have a alert message show on clicking a certain row, and showing the hold object at that my string is shown as ( "test tesT" ) could this be causing the issue with the table display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was what nss pointed to my data not being a string. I had to cast it when displaying it to the table.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]description]
```

The key word is description this casts it as a string